# JS: Insertar sólo el audio de un vídeo de YouTube (para más de una canción)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

He encontrado el siguiente código para, en vez de embeber un vídeo de YouTube en tu web, insertar sólo el audio:

https://blog-conocimientoadictivo.blogspot.com/2016/11/insertar-videos-y-listas-de-youtube-como-reproductor-de-audio.html

Le he hecho algunas modificaciones para intentar entenderlo mejor y adaptarlo a mi situación:

El HTML:

```
<span class="ml-auto"> <!--Reproductor de sonido-->
    <span class="audio-youtube" data-video="<?=$id_youtube?>"></span>
    <span class="caja-youtube"></span>
</span>
```

El JS:

```
/* 1. Carga asíncrona de la API Iframe de YouTube */

var tag = document.createElement('script'); //Creación de un elemento <script>

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"; //Definición del src del <script> 

var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; //Se toma el primero de todos los elementos <script> que hay en <head>;
//en mi caso es uno de jQuery que necesita Bootstrap para su funcionamiento

var newNode = firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); //Inserta un nodo (tag) antes del nodo de referencia (firstScriptTag) como hijo de un nodo padre (firstScriptTag.parentNode) indicado
//tag es el <script> creado
//firstScriptTag es el primer <script> del <head>
//firstScriptTag.parentNode es todo el <head>
//newNode equivale a tag
//Creo que lo que hace es simplemente insertar el nuevo <script> como el primero del <head>


/* 2. Función que crea un <iframe> conteniendo el reproductor de YouTube */

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() 
{
  var caja = document.getElementsByClassName("caja-youtube"); //<span> vacío
  var enlaceYT = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-youtube"); //<span> con el enlace de YouTube de cada canción
  var imagen = document.createElement("img"); //Creación de un elemento <img>
  
  imagen.setAttribute("class", "imagen-youtube"); //Le adjudica un id a la imagen
  imagen.style.cssText = "cursor: pointer; width: 40px; margin-top: 1.5px;"; //Le da estilos CSS a la imagen
  
  enlaceYT.appendChild(imagen); //Añade la imagen al <span> que contiene el enlace de YouTube

  var div = document.createElement("div"); //Creación de un <div>
  div.setAttribute("class", "reproductor-youtube"); //Le adjudica un id al div
  caja.appendChild(div); //Añade el div al <span> vacío

  var toggleButton = function(play) //Controla que se muestre el botón de encendido o de pausa
  {
    var boton = play ? "GddldI3.png" : "XrAWYmu.png"; //Si play = true muestra una imagen (botón de encendido) y si no otra (botón de pausa)
    
    imagen.setAttribute("src", "https://i.imgur.com/" + boton); //Le añade el src apropiado al elemento <img> creado antes
  }

  var reproductor = new YT.Player("reproductor-youtube", //Creación de un objeto "reproductor" a partir de la clase YT.Player proporcionada por la API, que además relaciona con el <div> creado antes mediante su id
  {
    height: "0", //Características del objeto
    width: "0", //Altura y anchura nulas
    videoId: enlaceYT.dataset.video, //Id del vídeo
    playerVars: 
    {
      autoplay: enlaceYT.dataset.autoplay, //Inicio automático
      loop: enlaceYT.dataset.loop, //Reproducción en bucle
    },
    events: //Eventos
    {
      'onReady': function(e) //Creo que hace referencia a cuando se termina de cargar el DOM
      {
        reproductor.setPlaybackQuality("small");
        toggleButton(reproductor.getPlayerState() !== YT.PlayerState.CUED);
      },
      'onStateChange': function(e) //Si termina el vídeo, se cambia la imagen a pausa
      {
        if(e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) toggleButton(false);
      }
    }
  });

  enlaceYT.onclick = function() //Al hacer click en el <span> que contiene el enlace de YouTube
  {
    if(reproductor.getPlayerState() === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || reproductor.getPlayerState() === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) 
    { 
      reproductor.pauseVideo(); //Se pausa el objeto reproductor
      toggleButton(false);
    } 
    else 
    {
      reproductor.playVideo(); //Se enciende el objeto reproductor
      toggleButton(true);
    };
  };
};
```

También hay código CSS, pero en mi caso no lo estoy usando.

Bien, el problema es que este código funciona según `id` y no `class`, por lo que sólo pinta un vídeo; mi intención es que se puedan mostrar varios, procedentes de un bucle PHP, cada uno con su `data-video` cargado en una variable:

```
<span id="youtube-audio" data-video="<?=$id_youtube?>"></span>
```

He probado a cambiar los `getElementById` del script JS por `getElementsByClassName` y los `id` del HTML por `class` pero, sorpresa, no funciona.

Supongo que haya que crear, mediante un bucle JS, un objeto `reproductor` a partir de la clase `YT.Player` por cada canción que pinte el bucle PHP...

A ver si alguien puede orientarme sobre qué hacer. Gracias por adelantado.

**EDICIÓN 1**:

He modificado la función para incorporarle un bucle `for`:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() 
{
  /* Las dos siguiente variables son conjuntos de elementos, no estrictamente arrays */
  var cajas = document.getElementsByClassName("caja-youtube"); //<span> vacío que albergará el reproductor de audio
  var enlacesYT = document.getElementsByClassName("enlace-youtube"); //<span> con el enlace de YouTube de cada canción

  for(var i = 0; i < enlacesYT.length; ++i)
  {
    var imagen = document.createElement("img"); //Creación de un elemento <img>

    imagen.setAttribute("id", `imagen-youtube-${i}`); //Le adjudica un id al <img>
    imagen.style.cssText = "cursor: pointer; width: 40px; margin-top: 1.5px;"; //Le da estilos CSS al <img>
  
    enlacesYT[i].appendChild(imagen); //Incluye el <img> dentro del <span> "enlace"; posteriormente, la función toggleButton lo convierte en la imagen del botón de YouTube

    var div = document.createElement("div"); //Creación de un <div> que albergará el reproductor de audio
    div.setAttribute("id", `reproductor-youtube-${i}`); //Le adjudica un id al div
    cajas[i].appendChild(div); //Incluye el div en el <span> vacío "caja"

    var toggleButton = function(play) //Controla que se muestre el botón de encendido o de pausa
    {
      var boton = play ? "GddldI3.png" : "XrAWYmu.png"; //Si play = true muestra una imagen (botón de encendido) y si no otra (botón de pausa)
      
      imagen.setAttribute("src", "https://i.imgur.com/" + boton); //Le añade el src apropiado al elemento <img> creado antes
    }

    var reproductor = new YT.Player(`reproductor-youtube-${i}`, //Creación de un objeto "reproductor" a partir de la clase YT.Player proporcionada por la API, que además relaciona con el <div> creado antes mediante su id
    {
      height: "0", //Características del objeto
      width: "0", //Altura y anchura nulas
      videoId: enlacesYT[i].dataset.video, //Id del vídeo
      playerVars: 
      {
        autoplay: enlacesYT[i].dataset.autoplay, //Inicio automático
        loop: enlacesYT[i].dataset.loop, //Reproducción en bucle
      },
      events: //Eventos
      {
        'onReady': function(e) //Creo que hace referencia a cuando se termina de cargar el DOM
        {
          reproductor.setPlaybackQuality("small");
          toggleButton(reproductor.getPlayerState() !== YT.PlayerState.CUED);
        },
        'onStateChange': function(e) //Si termina el vídeo, se cambia la imagen a pausa
        {
          if(e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) toggleButton(false);
        }
      }
    });

    enlacesYT[i].onclick = function() //Al hacer click en el <span> que contiene el enlace de YouTube
    {
      if(reproductor.getPlayerState() === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || reproductor.getPlayerState() === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) 
      { 
        reproductor.pauseVideo(); //Se pausa el objeto reproductor
        toggleButton(false);
      } 
      else 
      {
        reproductor.playVideo(); //Se enciende el objeto reproductor
        toggleButton(true);
      };
    };
  } 
};
```

Siendo el HTML, que está incluido en un bucle PHP, el siguiente:

```
<span class="ml-auto"> <!--Reproductor de sonido-->
    <span class="enlace-youtube" data-video="<?=$id_youtube?>"></span>
    <span class="caja-youtube"></span>
</span>
```

Si incorporamos un `console.log(reproductor)` tras crear la `var reproductor`, parece que funciona; en el caso de que el bucle PHP pinte tres canciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, el bucle JS parece ir machacando los elementos y sólo pinta el último:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto para tres listas diferentes; si se trata de una única lista con tres canciones, lo mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El único error que me aparece en relación al script es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error se repite, pero no parece haber n-1 errores (es decir, que sólo no fallase para la última canción), sino cierto número que no consigo relacionar con el número de canciones; a veces sí es n-1, pero otras no, es n-2 o incluso n-3.

**EDICIÓN 2**:

Dentro del `onReady`, he comentado `//reproductor.setPlaybackQuality("small");` y puesto `toggleButton()` a `false`, y los mensajes de error desaparecen, pero el reproductor sigue apareciendo únicamente para la última canción.

**EDICIÓN 3**:

He descubierto que al pinchar en el lugar en el que debería ir el botón reproductor de YouTube para cualquier canción, empieza a sonar la última. Falta un `this` por algún lado.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar lo que has intentado, sabiendo que no va a funcionar por ID en caso de que no sean únicos.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` te trae un arreglo de datos, podrias anadirle `[0]` si solo tienes un dato.

Comment: Con `var enlaceYT = enlacesYT[1];`, siendo `var enlacesYT = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-youtube");`, me pinta el reproductor para la segunda canción en vez de la primera. Seguiré investigando en esa línea. Gracias, Felipe.

Comment: Pregunta ... Has testeado el codigo de ejemplo?? Si te reproduce ??

Comment: Sí, consulta las ediciones para saber en qué punto me encuentro ahora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro que esto funcione, pero la propuesta es:

1. No apliques estilos directamente a la imagen creada, es mejor asignar una clase
2. En lugar de `.getElementsByClassName()` usa `.querySelectorAll()`, que te permite recorrer con `.forEach()` y facilita un poco el código, accediendo solo a la variable, sin índice
3. Recorre solo los enlaces y desde cada uno podrás obtener la caja correspondiente
4. Crea la función `toggleButton()` fuera del ciclo, para que tengas solo una, en lugar de una para cada reproductor. Debes enviar como parámetro el enlace y estado
5. Define todas las variables con `let` en lugar de `var` para limitar el contexto donde estarán disponibles; una forma fácil de explicarlo es que cada variable solo estará visible en el reproductor correspondiente, porque se crea en cada iteración del ciclo, mientras que con `var` se usa la misma variable para todos, actualizando valor en cada iteración

También se podrían crear funciones únicas para los eventos del reproductor, pero no recuerdo cómo acceder a los elementos del DOM desde el reproductor.

```css
.imagen-yt {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="ml-auto"> <!--Reproductor de sonido-->
    <span class="enlace-youtube" data-video="<?=$id_youtube?>"></span>
    <span class="caja-youtube"></span>
</span>
```

```js
// Crear solo una función para cambiar todos los botones
function toggleButton(enlaceYt, play) {
    let boton = (play) ? "GddldI3.png" : "XrAWYmu.png";
    // Obtener imagen, a partir del enlace y asignar botón
    enlaceYt.querySelector('img').src = `https://i.imgur.com/${boton}`;
}

function onYtIframeReady() {
    // Obtener solo enlaces por clase y usando querySelectorAll()
    let enlacesYt = document.querySelectorAll('.enlace-youtube');
    // Recorrer todos los enlaces
    // - enlaceYt es el elemento actual
    // - i es su posición en la lista de nodos (índice)
    enlacesYt.forEach((enlaceYt, i) => {
        // Crear imagen, asignar ID, clase (en vez de estilos) y fuente
        let imagen = new Image();
        imagen.id = `imagen-youtube-${i}`;
        imagen.className = 'imagen-yt';
        // Esto podría omitirse, porque se va a asignar cuando cargue el reproductor
        imagen.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/XrAWYmu.png'; // Imagen inicial
        // Agregar imagen al enlace
        enlaceYt.appendChild(imagen);

        // Obtener caja, llegando primero al padre del enlace con closest()
        let caja = enlaceYt.closest('span.ml-auto').querySelector('.caja-youtube');

        // Crear div para reproductor y asignar ID
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = `reproductor-youtube-${i}`;
        // Agregar div a la caja para poder crear el reproductor
        caja.appendChild(div);

        // Crear reproductor
        let reproductor = new YT.player(`reproductor-youtube-${i}`, {
            height: "0", //Características del objeto
            width: "0", //Altura y anchura nulas
            videoId: enlaceYt.dataset.video, //Id del vídeo
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: enlaceYt.dataset.autoplay, //Inicio automático
                loop: enlaceYt.dataset.loop, //Reproducción en bucle
            },
            events: {
                // Se ejecuta al cargar el reproductor
                'onReady': function(e) {
                    reproductor.setPlaybackQuality("small");
                    toggleButton(enlaceYt, reproductor.getPlayerState() !== YT.PlayerState.CUED);
                },
                // Se ejecuta al haber cambio de estado, puede ser fin del video
                'onStateChange': function(e) {
                    if(e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                        toggleButton(enlaceYt, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Ejecutar cuando se hace clic en el span del enlace
        enlaceYt.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Estado de la imagen
            let play = false;
            if(reproductor.getPlayerState() === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || reproductor.getPlayerState() === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) { 
                // Solo detener reproductor, play ya está en falso
                reproductor.pauseVideo();
            } else {
                // Iniciar / continuar reproducción y poner play en verdadero
                reproductor.playVideo();
                play = true;
            };
            // Cambiar imagen del botón
            toggleButton(enlaceYt, play);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Me pusé a probar tus sugerencias, empecé por cambiar `var` por `let` porque era lo más sencillo con el editor de código, y sólo con eso ya funciona exactamente como necesito. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

A ver si te podemos ayudar.

Primero Busca el video del que quieras insertar en una web el audio solamente. Cuando lo tengas, mira en el navegador la dirección web, ya que necesitas saber el ID del video, el conjunto de letras que viene después de ‘v=‘. En este caso sería ‘***BtV1-gJ_bm0***’ ya que hemos elegido un tema musical de **The Cranberries** (de las mejores canciones de todos los tiempos ;) ).

Ahora hay que añadir estas líneas al código HTML:

```
<div data-video="VIDEO_ID"
         data-autoplay="0"
         data-loop="1"
         id="youtube-audio">
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
```

en la web en que quieras implementar el video, y modificar la parte que pone ‘***VIDEO_ID***’ por la del video que cogiste del navegador.

**Edit:** Si lo necesitas dentro un bucle php para que pinte varias canciones, puedes hacerlo con el Bucle "*ForEach*":

Suponiendo que tengas los Videos ID almacenado en un array ($array):

```
foreach ($array as $videoID) {
<?
      <div data-video="<?php echo $videoID;?>"
             data-autoplay="0"
             data-loop="1"
             id="youtube-audio">
      </div>
      <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>

<?Php
}
```

Con esto ya deberías tener la ventana, con todas las conciones insertadas (o VideoID) de YouTube que tengas dentro del *$array* , y al darle a Play empezar a reproducirse. Si quieres que se reproduzca de forma automática puedes hacerlo simplemente cambiando en el apartado del código donde pone data-autoplay="0" a 1. Si quieres que el audio se reproduzca en bucle continuo modifica a 1 el valor del apartado data-loop=“0”. Este código renderiza de manera interna YouTube usando el reproductor IFRAME, por lo que funcionará tanto en navegadores de sobremesa como de smartphones.

Suerte y éxitos hermano!

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Amilcar, pero esa parte ya está solventada. Lo que necesito es que el script funcione dentro de un bucle PHP que pinta entre una y quince canciones.

Comment: entonces tienes varios videos?  Esos Videos_Id los tienes almacenados en un json, o un array, o una BBDD? Así puedo modificar mi respuesta con la solución correcta.

Comment: Sí, había puesto un segundo mensaje con mis avances, pero ya he incorporado todo ese texto como ediciones en el mensaje inicial.